# Clicking far away in vim in tmux in urxvt

Tags: vim, tmux, xterm, urxvt

I use vim inside tmux inside urxvt, and the mouse works perfectly well for clicking and selecting text, except when I want to click too far to the right.

It seems to be related to the distance in number of columns from the left. When I go beyond column ~200 (not sure about the exact number), clicking simply does nothing.

Note that it's not related to a vim window: with two vim windows taking ~150 columns each, clicking will not work after the ~50th column in the second window. It's related to the whole vim session.

Also note that clicking far away in a big tmux pane (>200 columns) works perfectly.

In my `.tmux.conf` I have this line:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

and in my `.vimrc` I have this:

```
if &term =~ "^screen"
    autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\033Ptmux;\033\033]12;7\007\033\\"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]12;5\x7\<Esc>\\"
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]12;7\x7\<Esc>\\"
    autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\033Ptmux;\033\033]12;14\007\033\\"
end
```

It changes the cursor's color depending on the editing mode of vim, and it works, meaning that tmux really sets `$TERM` to "screen-256color" — but I don't know if this has any relevance with my mouse problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, vim 7.3, tmux 1.6 and rxvt-unicode 9.14.

Does anybody have an idea about what is causing this problem? Thanks.

**Update:** I now use xterm and it works. I thought urxvt was required for unicode support, but believe it or not, xterm has unicode support too.

Comment: Just throwing in my +1; I, too, experience this problem. It only manifests inside a vim that is inside a tmux; and it manifests regardless of the respective configuration files. (For me, it's precisely column 223 every time.)

Comment: I've hit up the `tmux` mailing-list; we'll see if this is a bug. http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/message/34074071/

Comment: I updated the question to say that I've fixed the problem by switching to xterm. I know it's not the best solution but it works.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970472/371250

Answer (score 5):

So, thanks to [Screwtape](http://www.zootle.net/afda/cgi/bio.cgi?screwtape), I've got [an answer](http://tmux-users.narkive.com/d9OwLqPf/mouse-using-applications-inside-tmux-in-wide-terminals#post3) for this. Reproduced below:

---

The original `xterm` mouse protocol only supports up to 223 columns and
lines. Later versions of the protocol used UTF-8 encoding, which turned
out to be a terrible idea, and more modern terminals support
a completely different protocol based on the SGR escape sequence that's
much more sane.

`tmux` automatically supports the original protocol and the SGR protocol
both ways (to the terminal it's running inside of, and to the
applications running inside it.) but it only requests UTF-8 mode from
the outer terminal if 'mouse-utf8' is enabled in the config file.

You can use the `vttest` tool to experiment with different mouse protocols
inside and outside `tmux` to get a better idea what's going on.

According to the documentation for Vim's `'ttymouse'` option, it will ask
the terminal for original-xterm-protocol support if `$TERM` is a variant
of `xterm`, `mlterm` or `screen` (and `tmux` reports itself as `screen`, so that's
OK). If the terminal supports the `"RV"` termcap feature to determine the
`xterm` version number, Vim will use that to automatically upgrade to
`'xterm2'` or `'sgr'` mouse protocols... but typically only `xterm` advertises
`"RV"` support, so `tmux` is left out of the automatic upgrade process.

In my `~/.vimrc` I have the following code to enable decent mouse support,
instead of relying on Vim's autodetection:

```
" Screen/tmux can also handle xterm mousiness, but Vim doesn't
" detect it by default.
if &term == "screen"
set ttymouse=xterm2
endif

if v:version >= 704 && &term =~ "^screen"
" Odds are good that this is a modern tmux, so let's pick the
" best mouse-handling mode.
set ttymouse=sgr
endif
```

---

(Of note, the `set ttymouse=sgr` is the actual fix, here; I suggest [adding it to your `.vimrc`](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/System/commit/3feec0f) as Tim did.)

Comment: You can use `has("mouse_sgr")` instead of testing `v:version >= 704`

Comment: Using `set ttymouse=sgr` or `set ttymouse=xterm2` does not work in tmux in urxvt. You still can't click past the 223 column.

Comment: Hm, @paps, I don't have access to an urxvt to test. Can you check the other ttymouse values? And enable `⌃b :`, then `set mouse-utf8 on`, in the tmux you're testing with, for me?

Answer (score 1):

It's due to limitations in the mouse reporting protocol in terminals:
"*The original X10 mouse protocol limits the C x and C y ordinates to 223 (=255 - 32)*" see [this link](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#Mouse%20Tracking)

Comment: This isn't the case (well, I mean, if so, it's due to `tmux` or `vim` making assumptions about this; not due to the implementation in the terminal); `tmux` panes are manipulable beyond column 223 in my Terminal.app on OS X, and `vim` windows are as well; it's only when one is placed inside the other that there are issues.

Comment: Confirmed: this is definitely a `tmux` issue. `nano --mouse` shows the same limitations as `vim`, but only *inside* `tmux`.

Comment: I'm talking about the control sequences, tmux is itself a kind of terminal emulator. It interprets control sequences. I never said it was a terminal bug