# Use the mouse past 220 columns in Neovim with rxvt-unicode

Tags: terminal, vim, mouse, urxvt

When using neovim with mouse support in urxvt, any mouse events past the 220th column are wrapped around to the left of the screen.

The mouse works normally in vim, and in nvim with another terminal such as xterm

```
$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -O2 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/build/neovim/src/build/config -I/build/neovim/src/neovim-0.4.4/src -I/usr/include -I/build/neovim/src/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim/src/build/include
Compiled by builduser

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info

$ urxvt --help
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.22 - released: 2016-01-23
options: perl,xft,styles,combining,blink,iso14755,unicode3,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,fade,transparent,tint,XIM,frills,selectionscrolling,wheel,slipwheel,cursorBlink,pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm
Usage: urxvt [options] [-e command args]
```

How can I get mouse events past the 220th column to be read properly by nvim?

Comment: No time to write a post but see https://superuser.com/q/485956/1686 and https://bugs.gentoo.org/761787 for possibly related issue.

Comment: thanks, @user1686 . I've seen other issues similar to this but neovim changes how the mouse is handled from vim, so I can't find a way to set it to use the correct mouse protocol.

Comment: One solution is to use rxvt-unicode patched for SGR support - I don't consider this an answer, however https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rxvt-unicode-sgr-mouse/